# Migrating JAX-RPC webservice to Spring-WS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws, jax-rpc

I am trying to convert a JAX-RPC webservice running on websphere to spring-ws in springboot application. The existing customers facing issue connecting to the new webservice as it validates the content-type and soap envelope.

it is failing with a version mismatch ot invalid conetnet-type error. I thought of writing own message factory and edit content-type and soap versions.
not sure whether it will bring another troubles.

is there away to migrate JAX-RPC webservice to spring-ws

Comment: You cannot. Spring WS is for document based web services not for RPC based web services.

Comment: Thank you Deinum. is there a way i can migrate jax-rpc webservice into a springboot application ?